# PostgreSQL Error for Select Distinct in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

On Mysql it works correctly.

> PG::Error: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must
>   appear in select list LINE 1: ) ORDER BY
>   programs.rating DESC, program_sc... ^ :

Query:

> SELECT DISTINCT "programs".* FROM "programs" INNER JOIN
>   "program_schedules" ON "program_schedules"."program_id" =
>   "programs"."id" WHERE (programs.rating >= 5 AND
>   program_schedules.start >= '2012-11-03 23:14:43.457659') AND (ptype =
>   'movie') ORDER BY programs.rating DESC,
>   program_schedules.start DESC

Rails code:

> @data =
>   Program.joins(:program_schedules).where('programs.rating >= ?
>   AND program_schedules.start >= ?',5,
>   Time.now).order('programs.rating DESC,
>   program_schedules.start DESC').uniq

I have tried with

> Program.select("programs.*,
>   program_schedules.*).joins(:program_schedules).where(...

but, in this way, when I'm going to read

> @data.program_schedules

I get a nil value (When I know there are no nil values)

### PostgreSQL 9.2 (Heroku), Ruby 1.9.2

Some info about my DB:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :program_schedules
end


class ProgramSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program
end
```

Schema.db

```
 create_table "program_schedules", :force => true do |t|
        t.integer  "program_id"
        t.datetime "start"
  end

  create_table "programs", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "title",
    t.string  "ptype"
  end
```

**EDIT:**
I don't need to order "programs_schedules" because I need all programs_schedules in my array related to that program.

Comment: That's a complex enough query where I would just use `find_by_sql`

Comment: As *always*: version of PostgreSQL? Should go without saying for programmers .. Table definitions are never a bad idea either. Would clarify where `ptype` is from.

Comment: ok,I've updated my question post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You query is ambiguous in two ways:

`ptype` is not table-qualified and you did not disclose the table definitions. So the query is ambiguous.

More importantly, you want to:

```
ORDER BY programs.rating DESC, program_schedules.start DESC
```

At the same time, however, you instruct PostgreSQL to give you `DISTINCT` rows from `programs`. If there are multiple matching rows in `program_schedules`, how would Postgres know which one to pick for the `ORDER BY` clause? The first? Last? Earliest, latest, greenest? It's just undefined.

Generally, the `ORDER BY` clause cannot disagree with the `DISTINCT` clause, that's what the error message tells you.

Based on a few assumptions, filling in for missing information, your query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM   programs p
JOIN   program_schedules ps ON ps.program_id = p.id
WHERE  p.rating >= 5
AND    ps.start >= '2012-11-03 23:14:43.457659'
AND    p. ptype = 'movie'   -- assuming ptype is from programs  (?)
GROUP  BY p.id              -- assuming it's the primary key
ORDER  BY p.rating DESC, min(ps.start) DESC;  -- assuming smallest start
```

Also assuming you have PostgreSQL 9.0 or later, which is required for this to work. (Primary key covers whole table in `GROUP BY`.)

As for:

> On Mysql it works correctly.

**No it doesn't**. It "works", but in mysterious ways rather than "correctly". MySQL allows for all sorts of weird mistakes and goes out of its way (and the SQL standard) to avoid having to throw exceptions - which is a very unfortunate way to deal with errors. It regularly comes back to haunt you later. [Demo on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PoFIohBSM4).

#### Question update

> I need all programs_schedules in my array related to that program.

You might want to add:

```
SELECT p.*, array_agg(ps.start ORDER BY ps.start)
```

Comment: +1! Thanks for the video link in particular. I'm keeping that around for next time I find myself saying the same thing.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've updated my question post. Now I'm going to check your query